# vim plugin to autocomplete blocks in django templates but *not* a generic snippets plugin?

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-system

Copying this question over from https://stackoverflow.com/q/42474604/262108I recently started working with django templates and was wondering whether there are any autocompletion plugins for template directives like `{% block|if|... %}`etc that ***do not*** involve a snippets library.

I specifically do not want a snippet plugin because I find them quite distracting when editing code. Most snippet plugins would require digging thru' the docs and to figure out configuration to disable (rather than enable) snippets.

I am thinking something along the lines of [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) and [xmledit](https://github.com/sukima/xmledit) which does something like (assuming `|` is the cursor):

```
{% block ... %}|   <-- recognize I entered a "%}"

complete it to:

{% block ... %}
    |   <------- place the cursor here
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I copy my comment here then... 
 
If you really don't want a snippet plugin, then I'd recommend you to hack xmledit into what you're looking for as what it does is really close. => listen for `}`. Analyse what is before and copy-paste-adapt it in the next line.

Comment: BTW, SO and vi.SE have the same audience of people that answer questions. We're present on both "forums".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle:

- listen for `}`, not `%}`
- analyse the context to decide what to return from a [`:h :map-<expr>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3amap%2d%3cexpr%3e)
- the mapping shall be buffer local in order to avoid side-effects with other filetypes ([`:h :map-<buffer>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3amap%2d%3cbuffer%3e))
- The movements returned shall be in double-quoted string and escaped with a back-slash (otherwise, you'll see the text `<up><c-f>` inserted)
- I'm not sure whether autoindentation could be applied here ([`:h i_CTRL-F`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/indent.txt.html#i_CTRL%2dF))
- The result shall be put in a django ftplugin, and it'll even better to put the function into an autoload plugin, with its name changed to `django#_expand_block()` for instance.

Here is the result:

```
" EDIT: VA. Support if, for, block. And just copy the statement.
function! s:expand_block() abort
  " Ignore what is after the cursor
  let ctx = getline('.')[:col('.')-1]
  " get sure there is a '%' before the cursor
  let statement = matchstr(ctx, '^{%\s*\zs\(block\|if\|for\)\ze.*%')
  if !empty(statement)
    " Avoid triggering InsertLeave events
    return "}\n\n{% end".statement." %}\<up>\<c-f>"
    " Shorter
    return "}\n{% end".statement." %}\<esc>O"
  else
    return "}"
  endif
endfunction


inoremap <expr> <silent> <buffer> } <sid>expand_block()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip @luc-hermitte and the great breakdown of the approach ! That serves as good starting point, I'll attempt to build on that for all sorts of completiions like `{% (block|if|for)...`

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of fiddling around and reading a whole lot of vimscript docs/blog posts, this is what I came up with (starting with the accepted answer as the starting point):

```
function! VimDjangoCompletion()
    let matches = matchlist(getline('.'), '{%\s\+\(block\|if\|for\)')
    return empty(matches) ? "%}" : "%}\n{% end" . matches[1] . " %}\<ESC>O"
endfunction

inoremap <buffer> %} <C-R>=VimDjangoCompletion()<CR>
```

Edit: As @luc-hermitte points out in the comment below, mapping `%}` is a false good idea, since vim introduces a delay waiting for the next character when `%` is typed. I initially added that to avoid having the function being called for every instance of `}` (including when typing `{{ ... }}` which probably is more common than directives in django templates). However, trading off unnecessary function calls to avoid the delay appears to be a good thing because the delay can get slightly annoying. I'm leaving the code as is to give context for @luc-hermitte's comment.

Comment: Mapping `%}` is a false good idea. This will incur an annoying delay every time you hit a `%`, even when you're simply typing `{%`. The only way to provide a good experience to end-user is to limit mappings on printable characters to single keys, and to analyse the context. Also, to avoid name pollution, prefer s:functions over global functions. Or even better, autoloaded functions (but this is a thing we don't see the benefit in the first years). PS: `<c-r>=` is what we used to use, or what we still need when we need to move around  the cursor -- this won't make a difference here